# SQL Server 2014 Query to get closed and open trades statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2014

I have a table in my SQL Server 2014:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[tblTradeSuggestions]
(
    [StockId] [bigint] NOT NULL,
    [DateGreg] [bigint] NOT NULL, -- Date Stored as yyyymmdd 
    [TradeSuggestion] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [ClosePrice] [real] NOT NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

The DCL & DML script of the above table can be downloaded from https://1drv.ms/u/s!An7s9XmnfXFdg6dVEgS9-msdkk9GUg

Now I need two queries(a & b) as below:

Query 1: output the data in below format with the mentioned conditions

- Conditions:

  1. Only the first buy date after every sell date should be considered and matched with first sell date which is after the considered buy date for a particular stock.
  2. If there is buy entry for a stock after buy entry with no sell entry in between then that should be ignored.

Expected result :

[image: Result Format]

I tried the below query, however the above conditions are not met.

```
SELECT 
    ts1.StockId, ts1.DateGreg as BuyDate, ts1.ClosePrice AS BuyPrice,
    ts2.DateGreg AS SellDate, ts2.ClosePrice AS SellPrice, 
    ts2.ClosePrice - ts1.ClosePrice AS Diff 
FROM
    tblTradeSuggestions ts1 
JOIN 
    tblTradeSuggestions ts2 ON ts1.StockID = ts2.StockID AND ts1.DateGreg < ts2.DateGreg
WHERE 
    ts1.TradeSuggestion = 'Buy' AND ts2.TradeSuggestion = 'Sell'
ORDER BY 
    ts1.StockId, ts1.DateGreg
```

Query 2: list of stocks with Buy Date and no sell date after the Buy Date in the below format.

```
StockId DateGreg    TradeSuggestion ClosePrice
----------------------------------------------
4583    20150901    Buy             46.45
```

Could some please help ? Please let me know in case of any more information required.

Comment: Site note: I would recommend *not* to use `real` for any money values - `real` and `float` are inherently **imprecise** and susceptible to rounding errors. For money values, I'd recommend to **always** use `decimal(p,s)` instead

Comment: Can you please add the expected result as text

Comment: why are your dates bigint and not datetimes? surely trades dates should be specific to a precise time?

Comment: This just makes no sense and i can't see how something like this will give you reliable results. You have multiple results for a single stock id on the same buy date, so how can you match them up without something like a unique trade id? each trade should have a unique id, which will make your life so much easier. I can't really understand your logic and how this is ever going to produce anything meaningful.

Comment: For `StockId=4519` why only buy `4519 20160202 Buy 80,05` should be in the result ?

Comment: Hi, The buy and sell suggestions are inserted by jobs related to different algorithms. We will buy a stock only when the buy is suggested initially and ignore if its having a buy suggestion again before sell suggestion. We will sell the stock bought when the first sell suggestion gets inserted into the table and ignore the sell suggestions if we didn't buy that stock before the sell date. Ideally, any stock will have only one buy or sell suggestion for a particular date I am open to change the Table structure to get the required result as we are still not in production. .

Comment: Hi Tanner,The Trade Dates are dates stored in yyyymmdd format.

Comment: is [tblTradeSuggestions] your only table, or have you got another table telling us what a buy and sale is? - how do we distinguish between a buy and a sale?  You'll have to tell us what the sequence of data going into your table is, what it means, and think about whether or not there is enough info to go on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one

BTW, your explanation seems to suggest one-to-one, but your results seem to suggest that you want to map 1 buy to many sales, what if you buy,sell, sell, then buy, sell, sell?

```
    SELECT 
    ts1.StockId, ts1.DateGreg as BuyDate, ts1.ClosePrice AS BuyPrice,
    ts2.DateGreg AS SellDate, ts2.ClosePrice AS SellPrice, 
    ts2.ClosePrice - ts1.ClosePrice AS Diff 
FROM
    tblTradeSuggestions ts1 
CROSS APPLY
    (SELECT TOP 1 * FROM tblTradeSuggestions ts3 WHERE  
                                                ts1.StockID = ts3.StockID AND 
                                                ts1.DateGreg < ts3.DateGreg AND 
                                                ts3.TradeSuggestion = 'Sell'
                                                    ORDER BY ts3.DateGreg) Ts2
WHERE 
    ts1.TradeSuggestion = 'Buy' 
ORDER BY 
    ts1.StockId, ts1.DateGreg
```

to get the non matched buys

```
        SELECT ts1.StockId, ts1.DateGreg, ts1.TradeSuggestion,  ts1.ClosePrice 
            FROM tblTradeSuggestions ts1 
            LEFT JOIN 
            tblTradeSuggestions ts2 
                        ON      
                            ts1.StockID = ts2.StockID AND 
                            ts1.DateGreg < ts2.DateGreg AND 
                            ts2.TradeSuggestion = 'Sell'
            WHERE ts1.TradeSuggestion = 'Buy' AND ts2.StockId IS NULL
```

Comment: Thanks Andrew. The second query is working fine. With respect to the first query, there shouldn't be sell and buy, we need only Buy and sell, We should not  buy a stock which we are already holding i.e consecutive buys without sell in between should be ignored.

Comment: kiran.net - sorry I don't understand that yet, you'd need to give a worked example